# Conditional filter for typeahead

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typeahead

I have a dropdown and a `typeahead` textbox, the value of textbox gets filtered based on the dropdown selection, this all is working fine, the only problem is I want to avoid filtering textbox values when user select option `(Please Select)` and actually should show all results in textbox typeahead without any filtering.

I am trying to achieve it through work around but is there any standard method of it to avoid filter for few some value?

This is the filter this is actually filtering records `filter : { ValueDomainCategoryTypeId : systemTypeCatgory}`

Dropdown

```
 <select id="ddlSystemType_1" ng-change="SystemTypeChanged()" ng-model="systemTypeCatgory" 
      ng-options="categoryInstrument.ValueDomainCategoryTypeId as categoryInstrument.ValueDomainCategory for categoryInstrument in ValueDomainCategoryTypes">
      <option value="" selected>(Please select)</option>
 </select>
```

TextBox

```
<input type="text" id="ddlItem_1" ng-disabled="IsReadOnly"           
         typeahead-focus
         ng-model="aiisInstrument" 
         uib-typeahead="aiisInstrument as aiisInstrument.Name for aiisInstrument in AiisInstruments | filter:$viewValue:stateComparator  |  filter : { ValueDomainCategoryTypeId : systemTypeCatgory}" />
```

Comment: Is it possible to default "AiisInstruments" to have everything in the beginning and when you call "SystemTypeChanged()" method, AiisInstruments is reset to contain values related to the selected value from drop down. A simple suggestion as I don't know how you are doing this at the back-end so you can skip this suggestion if it does not apply in your case. :)

Comment: @jsmtslch I found the solution thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the way, just replaced filter like this

```
filter : (!systemTypeCatgory?'': { ValueDomainCategoryTypeId : systemTypeCatgory})
```

And it worked!!